# R - Looping through a data frame to search for matching subjects, and then performing an action if they match

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, dplyr, bioinformatics

I have something like the following, as a dataframe

```
ID      Date       Bug
3452   02/01/2020  A
3452   02/01/2020  A
6532   06/01/2020  D
8732   09/01/2020  C
3466   20/01/2020  A
3466   31/01/2020  A
```

What I wish to do is this: Start on row 1 column 1, take that ID number and compare it to the ID number on the next row. Here we can see the ID is the same, so now I wish to move onto the next column, which is date. I wish to compare the date of the first row we checked, with the second row. If they are within a 14 day window, then I wish to finally compare the Bug, to check if they are the same Bug. If all conditions are met, then I wish to run this entire algorithm again on the next row until it has found all consecutive rows where all conditions are met. Then, to add a new column that classes them as one entity. What I have currently is this:

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(3452L, 3452L, 6532L, 8732L, 3466L, 3466L),
                      Date = c("02/01/2020", 
                               "02/01/2020", "06/01/2020", "09/01/2020", "20/01/2020", "31/01/2020"), Bug = c("A", 
                                                                                                "A", "D", "C", "A", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                          -6L))

df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>%
  group_by(Bug) %>%
  mutate(Flag = c(FALSE, diff(Date) < 14)) %>%
  ungroup


df1$Episode <- ifelse(df1$Flag == TRUE, "Yes", "No")
```

Which gives the following:

```
    ID        Date      Bug Flag    Episode
1   3452    2020-01-02  A   FALSE   No
2   3452    2020-01-02  A   TRUE    Yes
3   6532    2020-01-06  D   FALSE   No
4   8732    2020-01-09  C   FALSE   No
5   3466    2020-01-20  A   FALSE   No
6   3466    2020-01-31  A   TRUE    Yes
```

Now some of this gives the result I want, as you can see. However when testing this framework with large datasets which I cannot share due to confidentiality, many of these are classed incorrectly. I suspect that the code is not comparing the Bug at the end. What would be a workaround for this? Additionally, the date appears to be causing problems. E.g. if you changed row 6's date to 01/02/2020, it is unable to perform the algorithm. What am I missing here?

Comment: I am confused as to whichpart of the results are incorrect. It may be helpful to provide an example where the code isn't working as intended alongside the intended result.

My understanding is that a row should be marked as an episode if the previous row contains the same ID and Bug and the date is within 14 days of that previous row (not 14 days of the first appearance of the bug).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this?
lag() and lead() are ideal for when we are comparing an element to the last or next element in a vector/data frame. You can compare the Bug using `Bug==lag(Bug)`

```
df1%>%
        mutate(Date = dmy(Date))%>%
        mutate(Episode=ifelse(is.na(lag(ID)), "No",
                              ifelse(ID==lag(ID) & Date-lag(Date)<14 & Bug==lag(Bug), "Yes", "No")))

    ID       Date Bug Episode
1 3452 2020-01-02   A      No
2 3452 2020-01-02   A     Yes
3 6532 2020-01-06   D      No
4 8732 2020-01-09   C      No
5 3466 2020-01-20   A      No
6 3466 2020-02-01   A     Yes
```

Changing the last line was fine with my code

Comment: I found a similar solution however the person who asked the question mentioned that this result isn't exactly what he wanted. I was confused by this also hopefully @Isa can clarify.

Comment: I think the OP means this output is ok, but the output with a larger subset of the data was inconsistent. The problem is therefore not reproducible with the given dataset, we may only guess

Comment: I am going to use this piece of code in my larger dataset, and report back with more details of whether it still goes wrong.

Comment: In my primary work script, after I read in the data from a csv and turn into a dataframe, i used this code

Data <- Data[order(as.Date(Data$collection_date, format="%d/%m/%Y")),]

when I do this, using your code I get the error:


Data <- Data[order(as.Date(Data$collection_date, format="%d/%m/%Y")),]

However even if I dont use as.Date, I still get this error

Comment: Please post `dput(head(your_data_frame, 10))` with the exact data you provided to my code, and paste the code you used, and the error.
Your last comment was a bit confusing

Comment: Unfortunately, as I am using medical data for my work, I am unable to share the output as that would be a violation. The best I could is provide the made up values I used in the question, but I guess you can't really help from that. It seems to me the error is in the formatting of the date?

Comment: I just realized you reposted THE SAME QUESTION you already posted a week ago. Why not just edit the previous question, @Isa?